# Did the EU agree to a customs union without freedom of movement in the latest Brexit deal?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

The Economist [has published](https://www.economist.com/britain/2018/11/15/the-beginning-of-the-endgame-for-brexit) a convenient chart explaining the "final" Brexit deal:

[image: brexit deal chart]

Does this essentially mean that the EU has agreed to a full customs union without freedom of workers movement? Or did The Economist misinterpret how the agreement would work?

Answer (score 4):

The Economist is being vague, probably because some argue that freedom of movement has ended (using a future post-transition period), others that it hasn't changed much (using the present context). **In fact most things will remain similar to what they** **are now** **during the transition period** and likely a few years afterwards. There are however new sources of friction for whomever wants to stay long term in the UK.

As for the [customs union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_Customs_Union) notice that it has no direct relation with the freedom of movement. Turkey is in the customs union. You probably mean the [single market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Single_Market) which requires the 4 freedoms to be respected. Not the purpose of your question but you can learn more about this [here](https://www.reuters.com/article/uk-britain-eu-banks/draft-brexit-deal-ends-britains-easy-access-to-eu-financial-markets-idUSKCN1NJ2TM) (in relation to the draft deal).

**NOTE:** This is a big document and I've only read a few bits and pieces. I've quoted specifically those articles because they seem to have little or no ambiguity. I'll try to update this answer if I learn something.

---

Indeed the Free Movement will continue <strike>for at least 5 years after the transition period</strike> during the transition period (refer to **EDIT1** for my source on this).

On the [Article 14 of Draft Agreement on the withdrawal of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland from the European Union](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/publications/draft-agreement-withdrawal-united-kingdom-great-britain-and-northern-ireland-european-union-and-european-atomic-energy-community-agreed-negotiators-level-14-november-2018_en) rules are set for residents in the host state:

> **ARTICLE 14**
>
> Right of exit and of entry
>
> 1. Union citizens and United Kingdom nationals, their respective family members, and other persons, who reside in the territory of the
>      host State in accordance with the conditions set out in this Title
>      shall have the right to leave the host State and the right to enter
>      it, as set out in Article 4(1) and the first subparagraph of Article
>      5(1) of Directive 2004/38/EC, with a valid passport or national
>      identity card in the case of Union citizens and United Kingdom
>      nationals, and with a valid passport in the case of their respective
>      family members and other persons who are not Union citizens or United
>      Kingdom nationals.
>
>    **Five years after the end of the transition period,**
>      **the host State may decide no longer to accept national identity cards**
>      **for the purposes of entry to or exit from its territory if such cards**
>      **do not include a chip that complies with the applicable International**
>      **Civil Aviation Organisation standards related to biometric**
>      **identification.**
> 2. **No exit visa, entry visa or equivalent formality shall be required** of holders of a valid document issued in accordance with Article 18 or
>      26.

Also things would look pretty similar for EU citizens the foreseeable future:

> **ARTICLE 17**
>
> Status and changes
>
> 1. **The right of Union citizens and United Kingdom nationals, and their respective** **family members, to rely directly on this Part shall not be**
>      **affected when they change status, for example between student, worker,**
>      **self-employed person and economically inactive person.** **Persons who, at**
>      **the end of the transition period, enjoy a right of residence in their**
>      **capacity as family members of Union citizens or United Kingdom**
>      **nationals, cannot become persons referred to in points (a) to (d) of**
>      **Article 10(1).**
> 2. The rights provided for in this Title for the family members who are dependants of Union citizens or United Kingdom nationals before
>      the end of the transition period, shall be maintained even after they
>      cease to be dependants.

But some of the articles (see 18) also set out the rules and guidelines for permanent residence (after the transition). This increase in bureaucracy  will necessary create friction for people intending to stay in the UK in the long term.

---

**EDIT1 (16, November, 2018):** As @phoog point out these articles refer to citizens in the host state (UK in this case). I didn't manage to find a clear assertion of freedom of movement rights in the draft (but again I haven't really read the document either). For now I can only quote the [EU press release](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_MEMO-18-6422_en.htm) on the subject:

> The transition period is set to end on 31 December 2020, taking into
>   account the initial request from the UK for a transition period of
>   around two years, and making it coincide with the end of the current
>   long-term EU budget (the Multiannual Financial Framework 2014-2020).
>
> **During this period, the entire Union acquis will continue to apply to**
>   **and in the UK as if it were a Member State. This means that the UK**
>   **will continue to participate in the EU Customs Union and the Single**
>   **Market (with all four freedoms) and all Union policies.**

Comment: "Free Movement will continue for at least 5 years after the transition period": not quite, at least not on the basis of the articles you cite.  These articles apply only to those "who reside in the territory of the host State."  But (non-Irish) EU citizens who reside outside the UK will not have freedom of movement in the UK by virtue of their citizenship.  Neither will UK citizens who reside outside the EU have freedom of movement in the EU by virtue of their citizenship.

Comment: @phoog You are right. I've tried to correct my answer and added and EDIT comment to refer to a new source. I was hopping to find the answer directly on the draft text but for now I can only refer to the press release. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: "I didn't manage to find a clear assertion of freedom of movement rights in the draft": I wouldn't expect to find it there. The consensus seems to be that UK citizens not residing in the EU will become visa-free travelers in the Schengen area, and vice versa, though there's some talk about requiring UK citizens to have visas if the UK starts requiring visas of any EU country's citizens (for example, of eastern countries). There's been some noise in the English press about UK citizens being subjected to ETIAS when it is implemented.

Comment: @phoog I was expecting that and others points to be clearer. Perhaps I fail to interpret this correctly but this seems to me like an unofficial extension to the negotiations. A bunch of EU members are already moving to have some guarantees about the 4 freedoms (among other things like fisheries) and Barnier already talked about an extension to the extension, days after the release of the draft. I don't think I can definitively answer the OP question without seeing the actual final deal (1, 3, 5, etc. years from now).

Comment: The bit about "Five years after the end of the transition period..." has nothing to do with rights and everything with paperwork. It means that you can no longer use a non-biometric identity document to prove your identity (and maybe rights), but must use one with biometrics or a passport. Quite boring actually and not controversial.

Comment: @PauldeVrieze I think it would be controversial if the UK remained within the single market like an EU member or Norway style member. It is effectively a watering down of the EU free movement. But as I mentioned this agreement feels more like "proceeding with the negotiations" than an actual deal for the future. Let's see how members and parliament(s) react to it.

Comment: @armatita It is very much not a deal for the future (except the political declaration - which does not have treaty status and is more a declaration of intent). EEA or Switzerland would not be a problem on the EU side, but would be very controversial in the UK as it would maintain the 4 freedoms in the market.

Comment: @armatita I don't think the requirement (to start using biometric documents) would be controversial if the UK remained within the single market (i.e., like Norway), because to remain in the single market the UK would have to accept the free movement directive and therefore drop the requirement.  The current plan to impose that requirement (along with everything else related to the "settled status" plan) assumes that the UK will withdraw from the free-movement system; a change in that assumption would require a change in the law.

Comment: @PauldeVrieze The issue I see here is how an EU citizen would be seen post-transition. May is currently claiming the end of free movement, the end of privileged access for EU citizens, and some kind of system of high vs low skill immigration. I don't see how any of this can be implemented without a pretty agressive immigration policy (by EU standards). If you look at the [fact sheet for free mobility](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/factsheets/en/sheet/147/free-movement-of-persons) you'll notice that most rules already exist if you consider that the UK was never in Schengen to start with.

Comment: @phoog That is also my assumption. The final deal will depend largely on whatever system is negotiated meanwhile. The thing is: why be so expansive about it now (500 something pages)? Political convenience, perhaps facilitating the approval of the deal at home? As things stand what are the guarantees from each side for a post-transition deal? Is this moving forward to a Canada+ or a Norway style deal? (or something else entirely)

Answer (score 1):

The customs union is not really related to freedom of movement. All the customs union requires is that the UK continues to enforce EU standards on all goods coming in to the UK. It does not require the UK to allow freedom of movement of labour, that's something that is tied to the Single Market.

In practice without a hard border there will be nothing to stop people simply walking/driving into the UK, but they wouldn't have a legal right to work or live there.

Comment: The customs union also requires its members to enforce a unified tariff system. The idea that a customs union primarily concerns product standards is baffling.  "In practice without a hard border there will be nothing to stop people simply walking/driving into the UK, but they wouldn't have a legal right to work or live there": indeed, they wouldn't necessarily even have a legal right (or even authorization) to *be* in the UK, let alone work or live there.

Answer (score 0):

Single market is more than having the same rules. It means that everything functions as if it is one market. It requires that one can do business as easily in the other country inside the market as in. The only challenges would be customer expectations (perhaps they have different cultural preferences, or would like labels in their own language). This is not only a matter of having the same rules, but also a matter of mutual recognition and much more intense collaboration.

The regulatory alignment only means that the UK will not be able to produce the same goods for a lower price because (as an extreme example) they don't need expensive environmental controls as an EU producer would. This would provide an incentive for smuggling and cannot be allowed.

Comment: The regulatory alignment means far more than "that the UK will not be able to produce the same goods for a lower price"; it also concerns aligning product standards for imported goods. But this question is about the customs union, not the single market.  They are different.  The customs union concerns, in addition to regulatory alignment, a unified tariff system.  The single market is more comprehensive, for in addition to the free movement of goods, it includes free movement of services, capital, and people.

Comment: @phoog Regulatory alignment is not, per se, part of a customs union. However, alignment is needed if you wish to eliminate checks at the border.  A customs union just means that the same tariff applies and only needs to be paid once. The goods aspects of the single market are significantly further than a customs union.